# How to access USB External Drive on iMac from Macbook Pro?

Tags: macos, network, usb, external-disk, file-sharing

I have an iMac with an external USB 1TB harddrive, running Mountain Lion. Under File Sharing I have added this external drive to my list of "Shared Folders".

I have a MacBook Pro also running Mountain Lion and I want to be able to access the external drive on the iMac, but it's not showing that drive when I access the iMac via Finder on the MacBook Pro.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Marcus, which protocols are you using to share (SMB or AFP)? Also, is an admin account running on the iMac that's sharing the external drive?

Comment: My main user account on both machines (which both have the same username) is an Admin account. Re SMB or AFP: I'm not sure - I'm a Apple newbie - I'm just trying to access the drive via the imac that's listed under SHARES in finder (so I'm guessing it's AFP protocol that it uses)? The only other thing I've thought of is that the USB drive is NTFS (though I'm using Paragon NTFS enabling me to write to the drives from MacOS).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've realised that all the time the external drive is NTFS file system, it won't share it, but as soon as I formatted it to Mac OS Journalled FS, it appeared straight away.